# SQL join most recent results in GROUP BY

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

I have the following table:

```
+--------------------+----------+--------+-----------------+
|JOB_RUN_DATE_TIME_ts|JOB_STATUS|JOB_NAME|UPSTREAM_JOB_NAME|
+--------------------+----------+--------+-----------------+
|                   1|         0|       Y|                Z|
|                   2|         0|       Y|                Z|
|                   3|         1|       Y|                Z|
|                   4|         0|       Y|                Z|
|                   5|         1|       Y|                Z|
|                   6|         0|       Y|                Z|
|                   1|         0|       Z|             null|
|                   2|         0|       Z|             null|
|                   1|         1|       X|                Y|
|                   2|         0|       X|                Y|
|                   3|         0|       X|                Y|
|                   4|         0|       X|                Y|
|                   5|         0|       X|                Y|
|                   6|         0|       X|                Y|
|                   7|         1|       X|                Y|
|                   8|         1|       X|                Y|
+--------------------+----------+--------+-----------------+
```

`JOB_NAME` is the job for which `JOB_STATUS` is defined. A job fails if `JOB_STATUS = 1`. One of my main hypotheses with these data is that an upstream job's failure spells bad news for downstream jobs. I am having troubling creating the table that will allow me to test this hypothesis.

Each row in the table represents a particular run for a particular job. For each of these rows, I want to know what the outcome of the last run for its upstream job was. Ultimately, my table would look like this:

```
+--------------------+----------+--------+-----------------+-----------------+
|JOB_RUN_DATE_TIME_ts|JOB_STATUS|JOB_NAME|UPSTREAM_JOB_NAME|PREV_US_JOB_STATUS
+--------------------+----------+--------+-----------------+-----------------+
|                   1|         0|       Y|                Z|                0|
|                   2|         0|       Y|                Z|                0|
|                   3|         1|       Y|                Z|                0|
|                   4|         0|       Y|                Z|                0|
|                   5|         1|       Y|                Z|                0|
|                   6|         0|       Y|                Z|                0|
|                   1|         0|       Z|             null|             null|
|                   2|         0|       Z|             null|             null|
|                   1|         1|       X|                Y|                0|
|                   2|         0|       X|                Y|                0|
|                   3|         0|       X|                Y|                1|
|                   4|         0|       X|                Y|                0|
|                   5|         0|       X|                Y|                1|
|                   6|         0|       X|                Y|                0|
|                   7|         1|       X|                Y|                0|
|                   8|         1|       X|                Y|                0|
+--------------------+----------+--------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

Notice that `null`s are populated for rows without upstream jobs. How can I create this view using SQL?

I know that using a partition will help to find the most recent record for each job, but I can't figure out the full recipe:

```
SELECT
*,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UPSTREAM_JOB_NAME ORDER BY JOB_RUN_DATE_TIME_ts DESC) AS seqnum
FROM
tb
LEFT JOIN tb tmp_tb
ON tmp_tb.UPSTREAM_JOB_NAME = tb.JOB_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `left join` does what you want:

```
select tb.*, tbu.status
from tb left join
     tb tbu
     on tb.UPSTREAM_JOB_NAME = tbu.JOB_NAME and
        tb.JOB_RUN_DATE_TIME_ts = tbu.JOB_RUN_DATE_TIME_ts;
```

Comment: I guess the MCVE I made was overly simplistic. The `JOB_RUN_DATE_TIME_ts` values are UNIX timestamps, and there are many, many different values in that field. It's not like a "day" field and every job doesn't run each day, so I don't think it's as easy as adding that additional join condition, as I basically need to get, for a given `JOB_NAME`, the most recent outcome associated with its `UPSTREAM_JOB_NAME`. I think the `PARTITION BY` work I started is the way to go, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: @blacksite . . . It is only possible to answer the question that you ask.  If you have another question, illustrate it with more appropriate data.